# Visual Studio 2010 - setting default form preferences when designing forms

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to set the default fonts preferences used in Visual Studio 2010 controls, such as in labels, textboxes, comboboxes and so on?

For example, all textboxes that I add to my form will have the font `Arial`, size `14`, bold, backcolor `yellow` by default, without having to change them by hand.

I know I can select them all and change the font manually, but I would like to know if such an option is available.

Comment: Depending on which language(s)/platforms you are working, perhaps CSS? :)

Comment: opsss .sorry...

Iam using C#

Answer (score 2):

If you set the font and colors on the form before you add any objects(buttons,textbox...) the font and colors setting will be what you set on the form for the object. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the hint ...still need some effective ways to auto change controls properties (î have textboxes, labels, listviews, ... i want to assign different colors and different font props. to them)....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to mix fonts, styles and colors on the same form, subclass the controls you want to use and assign whatever fonts and colors are required in the constructor.

Comment: thanks for the answer..good idea indeed, still will make me more work than doing it by hand ...but thanks for the hint